# How could tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: be called with a nil indexPath?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I finally tracked down a weird crash. It is caused by `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` being called with a `nil` indexPath. But how can it be?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // DEBUG
        if (indexPath == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Deleting row at nil indexPath in %@", self);
        }
        [self deleteItemAtIndexPath:indexPath fromTableView:tableView];
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
6    XXX     -[ListViewController tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:] (ListViewController.m:427)
7    UIKit   -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) animateDeletionOfRowWithCell:] + 85
8    UIKit   -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 73
9    UIKit   -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 31
10   UIKit   -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 45
11   UIKit   -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 503
12   UIKit   -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 73
13   UIKit   -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 31
14   UIKit   -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 45
15   UIKit   -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 503
16   UIKit   -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 489
17   UIKit   -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 525
18   UIKit   -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 381
19   UIKit   _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6155
20   GraphicsServices    _PurpleEventCallback + 591
21   CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
22   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 213
23   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 647
24   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
25   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
26   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 75
27   UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1121
28   XXX     main (main.m:16)
29   XXX     start + 40
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace showing where the call came from?

Comment: I have the same IndexPath error, but with another stack trace. Have you managed to fix the issue?

Comment: I have fixed the issue in my code. I had a call of UITableView:  reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: in handler of NSTimer . And sometimes this resulted in crash in tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: . But I don't understand how the crash may happen, because both methods are executed in the same thread.

Comment: And in deleteItemAtIndexPath, do you do some multithreading in that method?

Answer (score -1):

The exception is due to the presence of data at index but the indexPath is already deleted. You need to delete the array object at index.

Try the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
   {
      if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
      {
         [self deleteItemAtIndexPath:indexPath fromTableView:tableView];
         NSMutableArray * tempArray = [yourDataArray mutableCopy];
        [tempArray removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
         yourDataArray = tempArray;
        [tableView reloadData];
      }
   }
```